# Setting up the domain hosting temporarily and returning back when available

Tags: dns-hosting

I was working while DNS hosting of my provider was closed. Provider o3.ua. All IP's are pinging except for provider's DNS ip.
By sheer luck my irssi client didn't loose connection, I switched to ##linux and asked. They said to change /etc/resolv.conf. (nameserver 8.8.88)

Though I need temporarily server, they don't know how to not to write to file my domain hosting. I'm working and could forget and parameters and totally about it, so I need a temporary solution.
And if it is possible a quick dispatch to return and use my original /etc/resolf.conv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for local domain resolution, you could just add the google DNS server as a secondary or tertiary server, that way, when your primary returns, it will the first server consulted.